# jquery simpledialog2 scrollbar

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-plugins, simpledialog

I am using simpledialog2 to show the dialog.

I want to add an scrollbar as my content is huge.

Below are the poperties for my dialog

```
defaultDialogConfig: {
mode: 'blank',
dialogForce: false,
showModal: true,
headerText: '',
headerClose: true,
animate: false,
zindex: 9999,
blankContent: '',
themeDialog: 'b',
themeInput: 'e',
themeButtonDefault: false,
themeHeader: 'a',
callbackOpen: lockScreen,
callbackClose: unlockScreen
},
```

Comment: Put a fixed height & then style ur dialog with overflow: auto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#DialogID{
   height: 400px;
   overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: Where is the person who posted it :)